# Dynamics 365 for Operation Could VM accessibility

Tags: azure, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax7

Using Dynamics 365 for Operation Could VM (deployed in scope of the LCS subscription), there is a requirement to access the SQL DB directly using ODBC connection from excel. Customer is not happy with implementation via Odata or custom service.

Current problem: can't connect to AX DB using ODBC

Please, could You correct me, if I'm wrong: in case there is cloud D365 VM, deployed in scope of the LCS subscription, the VM deployed against client Azure subscription, but VM is hosted on the Microsoft Azure site, thus there is no way to maintain VM from Azure (only RPD connection for non-production systems) and even we manage to open the required port on the VM site, the connection is not able to reach the DB because of Azure environment. Production system is even less manageable as required MS service requests. Following my logic, the appropriate way is to use one of the supported by AX frameworks \ protocols as it's always accessible regardless of system type and etc

Answer (score 3):

You do not have direct SQL connection possibilities for D365fFO production environment located in Azure. Consider to use OData feeds, Logic Apps (MS Flow) or PowerApps (CDS Projects) instead.
If you planning to use direct connection for reporting purposes (read only), you able to configure copying the production DB to Sandbox and to another DB instance sequentually.
Also you able to restore DB on to production environment from Sandbox before Go-Live.